# How can I view the result of pg_escape_literal?

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to view the result of the PHP PostgreSQL function pg_escape_literal to see how it transforms the given string, but I seem to be unable to output it. The code I've tried is as follows, omitting all the HTML clutter:

```php
<?php
    $escaped = pg_escape_literal('Hello world!');
    echo "Escaped: '".$escaped."'";
?>
```

The output is

```
Escaped: ''
```

Both `pg_escape_string` and `pg_escape_literal` are meant to return a string with the escaped data, as per the [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-literal.php), and when I use `pg_escape_string`, the output is

```
Escaped: 'Hello world!'
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but I admit I am very new to this game.

Comment: Oh... I completely missed that, probably because it worked (?) with `pg_escape_string`. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I removed that comment. I now see that those functions allow you to omit that parameter

Comment: It worked though! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was a silly mistake, which was pointed out by Chris Haas in a comment, which was later removed.

When using `pg_escape_string`, one can omit the first argument, which is the connection to the database, for it to seem like it's working in my situation. I do not know if it is working properly in all cases and my guess is no, but it *seems* like it's working.

When using `pg_escape_literal`, the connection appears to be somewhat necessary, and the function returned an empty string without a connection argument. However, the following code

```php
<?php
    $conn = pg_connect("/* login details */");
    $escaped = pg_escape_literal($conn, 'Hello world!');
    pg_close($conn);
    echo "Escaped: '".$escaped."'";
?>
```

produces the following output, which seems to be... well... at least not empty, to say the least.

```
Escaped: ''Hello world!''
```

It also appears to work if I connect to any database at all, without necessarily specifying the connection in `pg_escape_literal`.

Thanks a bunch to Chris Haas for the clue.